# Relation between principal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a question about the following relation:

> Let $a,b\in R$ for some ring $R$. Then $(a)\subset (b)\ \Leftrightarrow b\mid a$ .

Is this true? I have tried to prove it and came up with this:

$"\Leftarrow"$ Let $b\mid a$, then there is a $r\in R$ such that $br=a$, so $a=br\in (b)\ \implies (a)\subset (b)$.

$"\Rightarrow"$ Let $(a)\subset (b)$, then $a\in (b)$, so it can be written as $a=br$ for some $r\in R$ and thus $b\mid a$.

Comment: It's  fine for me.

Comment: For the $``\impliedby"$ direction, you can add a step. Since $a = br$, any element in $(a)$ can be written as $at$ for some $t \in R$. Now $at = brt$. So $(a) \subseteq (b)$.